# How Can I convert this Weird looking data to Image in Web App?

Tags: reactjs, image, api

I am working on a React Project and I have come across a Problem with weird looking data. I am using an API which is giving me response data with `mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame'`. They are Frames and I wanna show those frames in my React FrontEnd.

The data I am getting as response is...
[image: Data Image 1]

[image: Data Image 2]

Now I want to use this Image Data and show it on my Web app. Can somebody please explain it to me?

Answer (score 1):

The response data you're getting is a multipart document ([multipart/x-mixed-replace](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/iana.html#multipart/x-mixed-replace)), which means there are many individual files/documents in it. It's up to you to split the response up into its relevant parts, which you might be able to do with an NPM package like [multipart-mixed-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multipart-mixed-parser) (no endorsement, just did a quick search and spotted it).

You might also have luck adjusting the headers you send along with the HTTP request that is prompting this response to get back a non-multipart document. This will likely mean you need to make more requests for the data, however. If you are sending `Accept: */*`, try something like `Accept: text/html` or `application/json` (whatever is appropriate for what you're trying to get with each request).

For what it's worth, the part of the response you are showing here is a binary (non-text) document in what appears to be a JFIF format (i.e. “a JPEG”). Those funny characters are the result of the byte data in the file being (mis-)interpreted as text. They don't really mean anything, but you can see that part of the file is intended to be treated as ASCII text (e.g. “JFIF”).

Comment: Yeah! you have explained everything very precisely but right now I need a Solution to code, can you help me with that? Also, the data that I am getting as response is being encoded by `cv2.imencode()` method of python in backend.

Comment: I tried those `Accept` terms and nothing seems to work also I tried `multipart-mixed-parser` and it also did not work.

Comment: Hey, I misunderstood the Encoding thing. So, the correct flow at backend is; 
`cv2.imencode()` method will compress and encode data to store it in memory so basically it will return the buffer array containing multiple frames (Thats what I think) and now that buffer array data is being converted in bytes using np.tobytes() method in python.